# How does the first heap exploit from Chapter 8 of 'The Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes' work?

Tags: assembly, heap-memory, windows-xp, exploit, shellcode

I have been working through 'The Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes' which can be found [here](https://murdercube.com/files/Computers/Computer%20Security/Wiley.The.Shellcoders.Handbook.2nd.Edition.Aug.2007.pdf) but I do not fully understand one of the exploits given on p.179 (p.205 globally) which can be found [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads76/sourcecode/windows/system/289370/Source_Files/Chapter_08/Shellcoders08sampleprogram05.c__.htm). This exploit attacks the vulnerable program found on p.175 (p.201 globally).

The shellcode which is jumped to as part of the exploit begins with "\x90\x90\x90\x90\x01\x90\x90\x6A\x30\x59". I used [this](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) site to dissassemble it, which shows this hex string is the same as 4 nops followed by "add DWORD PTR [eax+0x59306a90],edx". This instruction does not seem to fit in with the rest of the exploit from what I can tell. Replacing the "\x01" with a nop instruction yields 7 nops followed by "push 0x30, pop ecx", which makes perfect sense to me since we are trying to find the PEB which is at an offset of 0x30 into the TEB. However the exploit only works with the "\x01" left in and breaks if I change it to "\x90" (on a vanilla copy of Windows XP). Strangely, the exploit also works by replacing the "\x01" with "\x02" which really confuses me. Therefore, my question is what part does "\x01" play in the exploit and why is it not just a nop?

I think there is something deeper going on here which I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: changing `01` to `02` changes `ADD r/m32, r32` into `ADD r8, r/m8`, with the same operands, but note that the destination will be `dl` instead of memory, so the actual effect of the `add` is probably not relevant.  You should single-step it in a debugger and see what instructions are executed right after the `add`.  (I didn't read the links in the first paragraph.  If the code being attacked is too big to summarize in a reasonable length question, I'm not interested enough to take the time to read it, sorry.  Maybe someone else who's more interested in shellcode will look at this)

Answer (score 1):

The book says:

> There’s nothing tricky here; we overflow the buffer, do the arbitrary overwrite, let the access violation occur, and then let the ExitProcess fun begin.

So it seems that the `ADD` instruction is there just so it can generate an access violation. The `NOP` are probably helpful to make sure you get to the right place.

A little further on page 178, they mention the PEB making use of pointers at a fixed address. By changing those pointers, you can get specific code (your code) called and thus executed.

Since you are exploiting an allocation, the `HeapAlloc()` will do the work of moving the pointer to the right place (in the PEB). Pointer the goes straight to your code and gets called from the `ExitProcess()` which actually tries to obtain a memory lock (interprocess lock).

Obviously, once you are executing your code, you can very well do whatever you want. Not an issue here.

**Why does it work?**

One thing that the MMU (Memory Management Unit) introduced, is the ability to install software an "any" physical address and execute it as if it were at a different address.

In the old days, the Intel processors used the segment registers (like DS) to get a similar effect, but without memory protection (process A could read data from process B.) The 68000 process allowed you to write code up to 64Kb in size (32Kb to make it easy) and have it relocated anywhere. The old Mac used that capability pretty well.

Now the MMU gives you total freedom and Windows XP already used that hardware functionality. So... all programs (text) start at the exact same address. (something like 0x10000, if I am correct.) And many information used by the process are saved in the first 64Kb. That's readily accessible as good old globals. Useful to access parts of the system without having to do a `syscall` each time and having pointers to various parts such as the dynamic libraries (PEB stuff).

That means your exploitation just needs to know of those pointers and it can use them to its advantage. It is a bit laborious to get started, but once you get used to the drill, it becomes easy to see these exploits.